# RxJs loop on a list of observables one by one

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm facing a problem that I can't solve because of my low RxJs experience.
I explain to you. In my code below I have a request (`createSOFromTransportTask`) which is sent and it returns me a list of IDs.

This list is in a certain specific order (*ofsExample = [35, 46, 54,..]*).
So I loop over this list to print labels, but they print in random order since my `forEach` loop sends the prints too quickly one after the other.
So the server prints the labels according to the first come (*example: [54, 35, 46,..]*)

```
async onGenerateShopOrders() {
    await this._printService.checkUserPrinterLocation();

    this._loading.show(this._transloco.translate('ecoOrder.MESSAGE.LOADING.SHOPORDERS'));

    let input = { ... };

    this._store.createSOFromTransportTask(input).pipe(
        finalize(() => this._loading.hide()),
        tap((ofs: string[]) => {
            if (ofs.length > 0) {
                let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogInfoComponent> = this._dialog.open(DialogInfoComponent, {
                    disableClose: true
                });
                dialogRef.componentInstance.message = this._transloco.translate('ecoOrder.MESSAGE.SHOPORDERS.INFO', { ofs: ofs.join(';') });

                ofs.forEach((of: string) => {
                    // HERE, I need to send printLabels one by one
                    console.debug("Print OF :", of);
                    this._store.printLabels(of).subscribe();
                });
            }
        })
    ).subscribe({
        next: () => this.resetData()
    });
}
```

Does anyone have a solution to overcome this problem, it would be necessary to browse the list ofs and at each send wait for a return to launch the next one.

```
ofs.forEach((of: string) => {
    // HERE, I need to send printLabels one by one
    this._store.printLabels(of).subscribe();
});
```

I hope to have been precise in my request if you have any ideas I am a taker, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) from RxJs, which prevents the next observable to be fired unless the current one is completed.

And with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you can map the `ofs` array to an array of observables, then subscribe them all once

```
...

if (ofs.length > 0) {
    let dialogRef: MatDialogRef < DialogInfoComponent > = this._dialog.open(DialogInfoComponent, {
        disableClose: true
    });
    dialogRef.componentInstance.message = this._transloco.translate('ecoOrder.MESSAGE.SHOPORDERS.INFO', {
        ofs: ofs.join(';')
    });

    concat(...ofs.map(currentOf => this._store.printLabels(of))).subscribe()

}
...
```